# Using Pandas to add missing categories for each date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with columns labeled as Date, Jobs, Count.  Assume that there exist 4 total job types and not all job types occur on the same day.  A sample may look like below:

```
       Date      Job Count
0      2010/09/06  D     1    
1      2011/01/24  C     1    
2      2011/09/12  B     1     
3      2011/09/26  A     1
```

What I need to happen is this:

```
       Date      Job Count
0      2010/09/06  A     0  
1      2010/09/06  B     0    
2      2010/09/06  C     0    
3      2010/09/06  D     1    
4      2011/01/24  A     0  
5      2011/01/24  B     0    
6      2011/01/24  C     1    
7      2011/01/24  D     0    
8      2011/09/12  A     0    
9      2011/09/12  B     1  
10     2011/09/12  C     0  
11     2011/09/12  D     0     
12     2011/09/26  A     1     
13     2011/09/26  B     0     
14     2011/09/26  C     0     
15     2011/09/26  D     0
```

So basically, I want to add the missing job types to each date that occurs and have the count listed as 0.  Any ideas or references on how to do this using pandas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a df of all possible combinations then left merge your data to that combination df.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2010/09/06','2011/01/24','2011/09/12','2011/09/26'],
        'job':['D','C','B','A'],
        'count':[1,1,1,1]})

unqiue_dates = df.date.drop_duplicates()
unique_jobs = df.job.drop_duplicates()

dates = pd.DataFrame({"dates":unqiue_dates,"key":["key"] * len(unqiue_dates)})
jobs = pd.DataFrame({"jobs":unique_jobs,"key":["key"] * len(unique_jobs)})

columns = ['dates','jobs','count']
final = pd.merge(dates,jobs,on="key")

final = pd.merge(final,df,left_on=['dates','jobs'],right_on=['date','job'],
                how='left').fillna(0)[columns]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly and a lot more quickly than my original attempt!

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned about things being sorted?  If not, a simple set of loops may do.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame() # load your data here

for d in df.Date.unique():
    heute = df.truncate(d,d+dt.timedelta(days=1))
    for job in ['A','B','C']:
        if job not in heute.Job:
            df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(data=[d,job,0],columns=df.columns)],axis=0)
```